# Need Help with a basic sql query for my own search engine Implemention

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am doing a search engine implementation in java (eclipse)
i have a table named `tbl_index` where i save all the keyWords with a column named `keyWord` against which i save a URL in a column `url`.

Now if a have a search term that consists of more than one words, how would i write a query to find all the URLs which have all the words.

**table Info:**

column1 : `keyWord (nvarchar(50))`

column2 : `url (varchar(800))`

these two are collectively the primary key of the table.
Please suggest a way in which i dont have to change my talbe structure.
Although it would be helpful to point out any mistakes in my current schema.

Also please suggest some good indexing techniques to index the keywords i get from the html of the website(the column `keyWord`).

Comment: Maybe a reverse index may help.. this is what I did when I put an internal search engine. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_index

Comment: Why not just go full-text?  Is this just for giggles?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs what do you mean by full text? i have dozens of paragraphs against each url which i break into words and then insert this in the DB

Comment: @SaadMasood: That's basically what a full-text search engine does.  I'd recommend you look into implementing full-text searches on your databases.  If you are using SQL Express, you probably have to download and install the version that supports it.

Comment: And to add to what Jeremy said, look at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs  wont be there performance issues when i go for full text search when i have thousands of documents to search through?

Comment: @SaadMasood: that's what it's designed for.  You'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select distinct
  url 
from 
  tbl_index a 
where 
  (select count(*) from tbl_index b where a.url=b.url and b.keyword in ('word 1', 'word 2' . . .)) = n
```

where `n` is the number of keywords you are searching for and 'word 1', 'word 2' etc are the keywords.

I suggest you create three tables: one with one row for each unique URL, with a numeric id and the url name, a second table with one row for each unique keyword, with a numeric id and the keyword and then a cross-reference table with all the pair url id - keyword id:

```
create table urls (
  url_id int identity,
  url varchar(800),
  primary key (url_id)
)

create table keywords (
  keyword_id int identity,
  keyword nvarchar(50),
  primary key (keyword_id)
)

create table urlkeys (
  url_id int,
  keyword_id int,
  primary key (url_id, keyword_id)
)
```

In this way you should reduce the size of the data. The query above becomes something like this:

```
select 
  url
from
  urls
where (select count(*) from urlkeys join keywords on urlkeys.keyword_id=keywords.keyword_id where urlkeys.url_id=urls.url_id and keywords.keyword in ('word 1', 'word 2' . . .)) = n
```

It would be a good idea to have an index on the `keyword` column

**P.S.** this is the outline of a simplistic SQL solution, but as various people already pointed out in comments this is a problem best solved using a full-text search solution. As soon as you try to do something like stemming, proximity search, partial word searches, wildcards etc etc. any SQL-based solution will fall short.

Comment: i didnt mention the other two tables for the sake of simplicity. i have thoses inplace. the difference is only that im using `url` as primary key as it also acts as a foreign key in the table `tbl_index`. same with the `keyword`. and both act as the primary key for `tbl_index` just like u did.

Answer (score 0):

This will be basically 2 step process.

A. First break your search term into separate words like this:

```
String[] words = searchTerm.split("\\W+");
```

B. Then build your query by iterating over words array and create a query like this:

```
Select url from tbl_index where keyword in ('word1', 'word2', 'word3');
```

Here word1, word2, word3 are basically `words[0], words[1], words[2]` etc.

PS: You may not want to go for **exact match** of keywords in table and in that case I suggest using `rlike` clause in MySQL query for regex capabilities.

Comment: I think this query will return the url that have ANY of the specified keywords, not ALL of them

Comment: @Mimo: True but isn't it what OP wanted when he wrote: `how would i write a query to find all the URLs which have all the words.` or may be I misunderstood :)

Comment: `....all the words`, not `...any of the words` - e.g. if the Web page at `url1` contains ONLY `word1` and not `word2` your query will return it, and I don't think this is what is being asked.

Comment: i tried your query but it doesnt give me those URLs that have all three word in it. e.g 'I am Free'. these are 3 words. i want  Urls which have all three words in it. not all URLs that have any of the 3 words. i hope u understand the difference im trying to tell you.

Comment: @SaadMasood: Aren't you storing one keyword in one record. If yes then `I`, `am`, `free` will be stored in 3 different rows of the table and that can theoretically return 3 different URLs. It would have been better if you had provided some sample data from your table.

Comment: wont full text search affect performance when i have built a large say millions of documents.

Comment: If you have to scan text every time then yes it will be a poor performing search but if you use a search too like Lucene, Solr etc then they build & maintain an exhaustive search indices (in binary format) and perform very fast searches even when performing full test search.